# preg_split with square brackets

Tags: php, regex, pcre, preg-split

I have a log file with the following structure:

**Input**:

```
$logLine = "[2017-12-23 19:15:59:634187] [INFO] User SIMDesign successfully logged in."
```

And I want to get an array out of it (with preg_split or preg_match_all) like this:

**Expected output**:

```
[
 0 => '[2017-12-23 19:15:59:634187]',
 1 => '[INFO]',
 2 => 'User SIMDesign successfully logged in.'
]
```

or this:

```
[
 0 => '2017-12-23 19:15:59:634187',
 1 => 'INFO',
 2 => 'User SIMDesign successfully logged in.'
]
```

**Attempts**:

I already tried some hours finding a regex pattern but unfortunately I didn't found the right solution for me.

```
preg_split("/[][]/", $logLine);

[
    0   =>  '',                                         //this is empty
    1   =>  '2017-12-23 19:15:59:634187',
    2   =>  ' ',                                        //there is a space
    3   =>  'INFO',
    4   =>  ' User SIMDesign successfully logged in.',
]
```

The output is okay but not perfect.
I don't need the empty elements of the array ([0], [2]).
And I need to get rid of the space before the string " User SIMDesign successfully logged in."

```
preg_split("/[][]\s\S/", $logLine);

[
    0   =>  '[2017-12-12 12:12:12:132123',
    1   =>  'INFO',
    2   =>  'ser SIMDesign successfully logged in.'     //The first character of the string was removed (why?)
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `preg_split("/(?:\s*[][])+\s*/", $logLine, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want the info between the first set of brackets, but as those are special chars for regex we escape them: `[(.*?)]` -> `\[(.*?)\]`

```
$logLine = "[2017-12-23 19:15:59:634187] [INFO] User SIMDesign successfully logged in."
            ^--------------------------^
```

Then the second brackets, same logic:`[(.*?)]` -> `\[(.*?)\]`

```
$logLine = "[2017-12-23 19:15:59:634187] [INFO] User SIMDesign successfully logged in."
                                         ^----^
```

And 'the rest till the end' is `(.*)$`

```
$logLine = "[2017-12-23 19:15:59:634187] [INFO] User SIMDesign successfully logged in."
                                                ^------------------------------------^
```

With spaces(`\s`) between them: **`\[(.*?)\]\s\[(.*?)\]\s(.*)$`**, with a [neat little demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f2cc772a8591abe9fe93b543ddd4378e6cdb591)

---

I like the answer I wrote above more, but the preg_split page also documents a few flags you can pass along with preg_split(), one being the following. The reason I'm not a fan is because your 'hiding' the problem instead of fixing it.

> PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
>       If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by preg_split().

Comment: Really nice explanation. Thanks this works fine for me :)